# Why does Marshmallow return empty for multiple items but returns a single item?

Tags: python, flask, marshmallow, flask-marshmallow

I'm building an API using Flask and marshmallow to format the query results but for some reason `Filter.query.all()` is returning empty, but when I replace that with `Filter.query.first()` it returns the first filter. I've also double checked my database to make sure multiple entries are there. Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

```
from Model import db, Filter

class FilterSchema(ma.Schema):
    id = fields.Integer()

filter_schema = FilterSchema()

### returns list of all filters in Filter db

def get(self):
    filters = Filter.query.all()
    filters = filter_schema.dump(filters).data
    return {'status': 'success', 'data': filters}, 200
```

returns:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {}
}
```

while `Filter.query.first()` returns:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "id": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to guess without seeing what `Filter` and `FilterSchema` look like. Does `dump` in `FilterSchema` return an object with a `data` property? Also, when you say it works when using `query.first()`, do you mean you merely replace the `filters = Filter.query.all()` line or something else?

Comment: `FilterSchema` is just a marshmallow schema that displays the id of the returned rows: `class FilterSchema(ma.Schema):
    id = fields.Integer()`. Yes, I mean replacing `Filter.query.all()` with `Filter.query.first()`, I'll edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out for a schema in marshmallow you need to specify whether the schema is dumping multiple entries or not. When there is more than one, add `many=True` to your `FilterSchema()`:

ie: `filter_schema = FilterSchema(many=True)`

or even better, add a different variable called 
`filters_schema = FilterSchema(many=True)`

and choose which one to use depending on the data you want returned.